# Tcl socket connection to Rserver

Tags: r, tcl

I'm trying to make a socket connection to pass data from a software system that uses Tcl to pass some data into an R server to perform some more complex analysis that isn't easily done in Tcl and then finally pass the results back into the original system.

I see that Rserve might be the correct system to use as the R server, but all of the examples appear to be Java based.  Is there anyone who has built some basic socket connections from Tcl into Rserve that can provide some examples of how to make these connections and pass information in, perform some operations and pass the results back?

Currently, I can use Rscript to accomplish this by passing a text file exported from our system, but would like a more elegant solution communicating directly in binary form if possible.

Comment: The [Rserve protocol](http://rforge.net/Rserve/dev.html) looks a bit complicated, and googling doesn't lead to anything much…